# What if in Assembly language we dont write numbers in hex form and write in decimal instead?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

when we write len dw 10 what value is stored in len decimel 10 or 10h.if it is 10h then why ARR is written as shown.Can't we directly assign the decimal values.

```
ARR DW 0000H,1111H,2222H,3333H,4444H,5555H,6666H,7777H,8888H,9999H
LEN DW 10
```

Comment: It doesn't matter for virtually all assemblers. All generally take 1-9... as decimal x... as hex and 0... as octal.

Comment: this does'nt answer my question.Can you please be more specific

Comment: Let's start with which assembler you are using?

Comment: 8086 assembler masm

Comment: This started with [discussion on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849186/how-is-the-cx-register-automatically-gets-decremented-even-when-i-dont-decremen#comment84702718_48849186).  See that thread for more context on what the OP is wondering.  (Which should be put into the question; people can't answer if they don't understand what you're thinking.)

Comment: my question is what if we write... "len dw 12" and "len dw 12h" in 8086 .Are they both different

Comment: I am a newbie in ALP ,please dont demotivate me by downvoting my answer or marking it as duplicate

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar `12` is a decimal constant, `12h` is a hexadecimal constant which is equal to 18 in decimal

Comment: assembly language is defined by the assembler, the program that reads it, although some assemblers will share the same syntax, you cant rely on that.  As pointed out below one assembler may choose to have hex as the default not decimal so 12 and 12h can be the same FOR THAT ASSEMBLER, but no reason to assume that is true everywhere, just like 12 being decimal and 12h hex is also not universally true, no reason to assume the 12h syntax is support $12 maybe be supported instead or 0x12 may be the only hex format supported for THAT assembler.

Comment: you want to write assembly language you learn the language for the assembler you are using.  also note the dissassembler from the same toolchain may not produce proper assembly language for the assembler from that toolchain (gnu being one example and not talking about all the extra info the disassemblyer provides but the mnemonic).  No reason to expect that to be true either.

Comment: One reason to use hexadecimal is that then exactly 2 digits will fit in a byte. With decimal values 100 is one byte but 500 needs two bytes.

Answer (score 3):

`0ah` and `10` are 2 different ways of writing the same value, i.e. they assemble to the same bytes in memory.

Pick whichever one is more readable / has more appropriate semantic meaning in your context.

Also note that the assembler output is binary, not hex or decimal or any other ASCII text representations of values.

Comment: my question is what if we write... "len dw 12" and "len dw 12h" in 8086 .Are they both different

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar: yes, of course.  They would only be the same if `12` was interpreted as a hex constant.  (Fun fact: apparently `debug.exe` *does* work that way: all constants are hex constants, and there's no way to override it to decimal.)  But all other assembler interpret plain numbers with no suffix as decimal.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar The point is to choose the value you need and then write in the way makes the most sense. If you want the value one hundred, you'd probably want to write it as 100. If you want the bit pattern 01100100, you might want to write it as 01100100b or, for conciseness, 64h. If you want the character Latin small letter d, you could write it as 'd'.  (They are all the same value actually.)

Answer (score 1):

In answer to you your question, you can use whatever type number you like. MASM provide specifiers to remove any ambiguity. From the MASM manual:

The specifiers are:

> ```
> y for binary      (or if the default radix is not hexadecimal)
> 0 or q for octal 
> t for decimal     (or d  if the default radix is not hexadecimal)
> h for hexadecimal
> ```

Radix specifiers can be either uppercase or lowercase letters; sample code in this book is in lowercase.